# Escaping slash in JavaScript via escape_javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, escaping, html-escape-characters

I'm not sure if my question is relevant to my problem, since the syntax coloring is playing tricks on me

I want to append HTML to an element.

```
 <a href=\'http://www.google.com\'>link<\/a>
```

Assume it the the result of calling a helper - getLink

so when I do

```
var newelem = "<%= getLink %>"
```

I get `"  <a href=\'http://www.google.com\'>link<\/a>"`
but starting from the // the rest of the line is colored green.. indicating that it is a comment?

Should I (and how) escape this double slash? is it a problem?

I added a picture to illustrate the coloring

[image]

Comment: We would need to see the rest of the surrounding JavaScript produced. I suspect though, that this is just your editor not knowing what's right..

Comment: so there is no need to escape the `//` you say?

Comment: No, not if it is in a string.  That's why I want to see the JS code this produced. If there is an outer set of single or double quotes, those slashes are just part of the string and require no escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chrome was misbehaving.. so marking this question as answered